# How to solve? ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'undefined' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to insert form data into MySQL database in nodejs using expressjs

When I run my code in command prompt it ran well but when I press the submit button, I got the following errors:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password:'',
  database : 'test'
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
        res.render("home");
});

//when I press submit button it should post the request and render a page to submit route with text "data saved!!" 

app.post("/submit", function(req, res){

  var q = "Insert into test (ID, name, crash1, crash2, crash3) VALUES (null, '" + req.body.ANR + "', " + req.body.crash1 + ", " + req.body.crash2 + ", " + req.body.crash3 +")";
  connection.query(q, function(err){
      if(err) throw err
      res.render("home", {message: 'data saved!!'});
  })
});
```

I created a table in MySQL Command line

```
create table xyz(
    ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    crash1 BIGINT, 
    crash2 BIGINT, 
    crash3 BIGINT
);
```

when I inserted manually it worked!

```
insert into xyz(ID, name, crash1, crash2, crash3) VALUES (1,'REERE', 2 ,2 ,2);
```

my error looks like this
[image]

Comment: What does `req.body` contain? Are you sure you don't have to quote any of the used colum names? For example, `name` is a reserved keyword in MySQL

Comment: When I did console.log(req.body) I got the following output:                         {name: 'hey there',
  crash1: '2',
  crash2: '2',
  crash3: '2',
  submit: ' ' }                                                                                                              I think I have data type problem! but I am not sure what should I do to fix this error!

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting into test table in your code:

```
var q = "Insert into test (ID, name, crash1, crash2, crash3) VALUES (null, '" + req.body.ANR + "', " + req.body.crash1 + ", " + req.body.crash2 + ", " + req.body.crash3 +")";
```

But table name is xyz. You should replace test by xyz and it should work.

And don't pass null in id as well as id is not null.

Please convert crash1, crash2, crash3 into int value:

```
req.body.crash1 = parseInt(req.body.crash1);
req.body.crash2 = parseInt(req.body.crash2);
req.body.crash3 = parseInt(req.body.crash3);
```

It should be like:

```
var q = "Insert into xyz (name, crash1, crash2, crash3) VALUES ('" + req.body.ANR + "', " + req.body.crash1 + ", " + req.body.crash2 + ", " + req.body.crash3 +")";
```

Comment: What should I pass as id instead of null?

Comment: I changed that line of code but still, that error say:                                              
                                                                                                                                       throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'undefined' in 'field list'

Comment: @YogirajZala Are you getting this error after converting crash1, crash2, crash3 into int as well?

Comment: Yey, I just got that issue solved!! Thanks for your support guys :)